# jQuery / Javascript error: myvar[i] is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Why am I getting this error?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $('.stuff').each(function(){

    function thing(id, count){
      this.id = id;      
      this.count = count;
    }

    var myvar = new Array();
    myvar.push(new thing('one', '134'));
    myvar.push(new thing('two', '225'));


    $('a', this).click(function(event){
       var i = $(this).attr('class'); // class is 'one', 'two' etc...
       // myvar[i] appears undefined here! wtf?

    });    
  });  

});
```

Comment: You have an extra paren, it should be `var i = $(this).attr('class');` or is that a typo?

Comment: it's typo, the error is still there :(

Comment: @can you print the value of i in console.log or alert i value , it might be wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to access an index based (0,1,2) array with a string index (i, the result of attr('class')).

Easiest fix is to use an object (aka fake hash array) for myvar and set the keys to the class names.

```
var myvar = {
  one : 134,
  two : 225
};
```

With that myvar, you can still use myvar[i] with i being the string index (one, two...)

Comment: thanks, myvar[i] now works :D but i remember that objects can be accessed another way, with dots or something like that. I tried with `myvar.i` but doesn't work

Comment: @Alexandra myvar["string"] is the same as myvar.string for objects. The second form has limits though, such as the string can't start with a number and it can't be certain reserved words. If you want to use the value of `i` you need to use myvar[i], because `myvar.i` is the same as `myvar["i"]`

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of "i"?
I suspect you are not getting a myvar = null, but myvar[0] = null because you have not added any data to the array.

Can you include the script within the anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

As i said , your value i might be wrong ,

it should start with 0,1,2 et .... print the value or alert and check it

```
$('a', this).click(function(event){
       var i = $(this).attr('class'); // class is 'one', 'two' etc...
       // myvar[i] appears undefined here! wtf?

    });
```